# Chrome couldn't destroy the session when it close

Tags: php, session

```
//1st page
session_start();
$_SESSION['a']=1;
//2nd page
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['a'];
```

I couldn't destroy session when chrome close the browser, i have tried add

`session_set_cookie_params(0);` or `session_cache_expire(1);`

those are not working, I read lots post, just cant find the solution.

Comment: Did you close browser itself or just close 1 st page tab?

Answer (score 1):

try creating a new page to destroy ur session

```
//1st page
session_start();
$_SESSION['a']=1;
<a href="end.php"> End Session</a>

//2nd page(end.php)
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: what im asking is when browser close, it auto destroy session

Comment: it wont destroy instantly but rather after the default time is due (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233924/what-is-the-default-session-expiration-time-in-php) the would it destroy